# How can I keep the data from being crowded together in matplotlib scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I run my code, and then I get the following figure.

[image: figure_1]

When I modify the value of figure options I get the output I want.

[image: figure_2]

What should I do with my code? How can I set the left and right values in code?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdate
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime
from decimal import Decimal
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
register_matplotlib_converters()

data =[(datetime.date(2019, 12, 23), Decimal('0.3230'), Decimal('157.89')),
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 23), Decimal('0.1680'), Decimal('157.74')),  
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 23), Decimal('0.1440'), Decimal('152.78')),  
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 24), Decimal('0.1070'), Decimal('157.94')),  
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 24), Decimal('0.6420'), Decimal('159.81')),   
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 25), Decimal('0.0980'), Decimal('115.31')),   
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 26), Decimal('0.0830'), Decimal('122.89')),    
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 26), Decimal('0.1600'), Decimal('171.88')),   
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 27), Decimal('0.1710'), Decimal('161.40')),   
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 30), Decimal('0.0590'), Decimal('161.02')),   
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 30), Decimal('0.4150'), Decimal('168.19')),   
       (datetime.date(2019, 12, 31), Decimal('0.1150'), Decimal('167.83')),   
       (datetime.date(2020, 1, 2), Decimal('0.0790'), Decimal('192.41')),   
       (datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), Decimal('0.4930'), Decimal('216.43')),   
       (datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), Decimal('0.2640'), Decimal('154.92')),   
       (datetime.date(2020, 1, 3), Decimal('0.1980'), Decimal('211.11')),   
       (datetime.date(2020, 1, 10), Decimal('0.2173'), Decimal('248.64')),   
       (datetime.date(2020, 1, 13), Decimal('1.3202'), Decimal('196.34')),   
       (datetime.date(2020, 1, 14), Decimal('0.0423'), Decimal('198.30')),   
       (datetime.date(2020, 1, 16), Decimal('0.0236'), Decimal('296.56')),   
       (datetime.date(2020, 1, 16), Decimal('0.0937'), Decimal('304.03'))]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.rename(columns={0:'a',1:'b',2:'c'},inplace=True)
x = df.a
y = df.c
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(x,y,facecolor='g',alpha=0.5)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdate.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
ax.set_xticks(x.drop_duplicates())
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the x-axis limits directly using `ax.set_xlim`. You can get the maximum and minimum from the dataframe returned by `x.drop_duplicates()` and then pad by a small time delta like this

```py
# ...
_x = x.drop_duplicates()
ax.set_xticks(_x)
# Create a 2-day timedelta and set the limits from the min and max with td as padding
td = datetime.timedelta(days=2)
ax.set_xlim([min(_x)-td, max(_x)+td])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

This will give you

[image]

I would recommend also setting a wider figure, i.e.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
```

Which will give you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an unfortunate consequence of autoscaling of collections. The issue is [#7413](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7413) and a solutions is in [#13642](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/13642). The problem will hence not occur in matplotlib 3.2.

Up to then, you can do a hacky manual autoscaling by adding and removing a line plot of the same data as the scatter. I.e. in the code from the question, replace `ax.scatter(...)` by

```
def myautoscale(sc):
    ax = sc.axes
    x, y= sc.get_offsets().T
    line, = ax.plot(x,y)
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    line.remove()

sc = ax.scatter(x,y, facecolor='g', alpha=0.5)
myautoscale(sc)
```